# Limitations on image base address

Tags: assembly, dll, exe

I have compiled a small assembler program and set the image base address to a rather unusual value: 0x048C0F40. The compiler (FASM) does not complain. Opening the executable in Stud_PE, it shows that base address. When I try to run the application, Windows says:

```
MyApp.exe is not a valid Win32 application.
```

(or maybe similar, because I only have the German text). (I'm using Windows 7 x64 SP1 if that should be relevant to get the error message.)

The executable can be run without that error message as soon as I use a base address ending with 0000 (0xZZZZ0000).

**What are the limitations on the base address of DLLs / executables in Windows? And what is the reason for that limitation?**

I thought that the limitation is just to be a multiple of 4 (although I have no source for that at this time). I also know that Visual Studio can only use [multiple of 64k](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7f5138s.aspx) in its `/base` command line switch. Some other sources I found on the Internet also mention that the last 4 digits should be 0, but there's no reason mentioned.

One reason I could imagine is the 64k granularity of VirtualAlloc(), but that could also change some day.

Comment: Does the image become valid if you change the base address to something legitimate, like 0x10000000?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Good point which I didn't mention: yes, it becomes valid then.

Comment: I'd guess at IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SectionAlignment, it is 64K.  That it matches the VM granularity surely is no accident.  I can't possibly guess at why this matters though.

Comment: Aligning by page boundary kinda makes sense... Pages are 4KB though (8KB on 64 bits).